# I want to apply custom discount of some percentage to cart total in magento 2

Tags: magento2, discount

How to apply custom discount of some percentage like (10%,20%) of cart total once he chose use custom discount button and if he want to remove the custom discount from the cart total in front end how can i proceed.

I want to show same as apply discount code section.in frontend

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to apply discount programmatically ?

Comment: Yes, @Sameer Bhayani

Comment: I have updated answer. Hopefully it will help you

Answer (score 2):

**etc/sales.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Sales:etc/sales.xsd">
    <section name="quote">
        <group name="totals">
            <item name="testdiscount" instance="MagePal\TestDiscount\Model\Quote\Discount" sort_order="500"/>
        </group>
    </section>
</config>
```

**Discount.php Model file**

```
public function collect(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
    ) {
        parent::collect($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);
        //$address             = $shippingAssignment->getShipping()->getAddress();
        $label               = 'My Custom Discount';
        $discountAmount      = -10;   
        $appliedCartDiscount = 0;
        if($total->getDiscountDescription()) {
            // If a discount exists in cart and another discount is applied, the add both discounts.
            $appliedCartDiscount = $total->getDiscountAmount();
            $discountAmount      = $total->getDiscountAmount()+$discountAmount;
        $label               = $total->getDiscountDescription().', '.$label;
        }    

        $total->setDiscountDescription($label);
    $total->setDiscountAmount($discountAmount);
    $total->setBaseDiscountAmount($discountAmount);
        $total->setSubtotalWithDiscount($total->getSubtotal() + $discountAmount);
        $total->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount($total->getBaseSubtotal() + $discountAmount);

       if(isset($appliedCartDiscount)) {
        $total->addTotalAmount($this->getCode(), $discountAmount - $appliedCartDiscount);
        $total->addBaseTotalAmount($this->getCode(), $discountAmount - $appliedCartDiscount);
    } else {
        $total->addTotalAmount($this->getCode(), $discountAmount);
        $total->addBaseTotalAmount($this->getCode(), $discountAmount);
    }

        return $this;
    }
```

**checkout_cart_index.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.totals">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="block-totals" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="before_grandtotal" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="testdiscount" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Discount</item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**checkout_index_index.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="totals" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="testdiscount" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Discount</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**You can also refer https://github.com/magepal/stackexchange/tree/develop/104112**

Comment: how can it be performed on any action? It should not be mandatory to discount the cart.

Comment: It will trigger each time when your total / quote update on any event.

Answer (score 1):

From admin panel go to Marketing > Promotions > Cart Price Rules and create a discount rule there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an advanced function my suggestion:

https://github.com/hodongnhut/magento2-payment-discount

[image]